# AS3:: an array of loaded through xml images with different widths

Tags: xml, arrays, actionscript-3, image-gallery

How to write the `mini[i].x = i * 1280;`? line, in the code below, to load images one next to the another.

Let's say 7 images - all with different widths. Because this `mini[i].x = i * 1280;` works only for image with the same width.

```
xml1 = new XML(URLLoader(event.target).data);
var i:Number;
mini = new Array(xml1.obrazek.length());            
count = xml1.obrazek.length();
for (i=0; i<count; i++)
{   
    mini[i] = new Miniaturka(xml1.obrazek[i].attribute("id"),i);
    addChild(mini[i]);
    mini[i].x = i * 1280;
}
```

I wan't to create a galery like you can find in this website...:

http://www.adartis.pl/#portfolio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a variable to keep track of the current `x` position, and keep adding to it as you loop over the objects:

```
xml1 = new XML(URLLoader(event.target).data);
var i:Number;
var currentX:Number = 0;
mini = new Array(xml1.obrazek.length());            
count = xml1.obrazek.length();
for (i=0; i<count; i++)
{   
    mini[i] = new Miniaturka(xml1.obrazek[i].attribute("id"),i);
    addChild(mini[i]);
    mini[i].x = currentX;
    currentX += mini[i].width;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Since gathering the width of the object is an asynchronous process, you will likely need to  wait until each `Miniaturka` has received its width from the `sizeHandler` method before attempting to create and position the next instance of `Miniaturka`.

One way you can do this is to re-dispatch the `PARSE_COMPLETE` event from your `sizeHandler` and listen for that event in the code where you're instantiating `Miniaturka`.

You would have to get rid of the for-loop, and instead position the old instance and create the new instance once the event has been handled.

Comment: Ok, but what when i can't get the loaded img width from the other class. I allredy tried everything ;/